# How to draw automata?

Tags: java, automata

I am doing some kind of composition of automata. So I want to visualize/ draw the composed automata for more clarity. I have done the coding in java. So can anyone suggest any library or tool which can be used for this. I have no idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) is my preferred tool for doing any kind of graph based visualizations.  There are some Java wrappers written on top of it (such as [grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/)), but it's also simple to use from the command line if you just want to hack something together.